# Having questions in your favorite tags as your stackoverflow homepage

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching, homepage

I was wondering why did stackoverflow never implemented this, but it would be really handy if there was a page that combined all of your questions in your favorite tags so you don't have to click on each tag, read questions with that tag, then go back to your main page, view questions with another tag etc.

Comment: This kinda is the case already. The questions you see on the homepage are biased towards your favorite tags as well as tags for which you have provided good answers for.

Comment: However, the first 20 questions on my homepage has about 40% that's contained with my favorite tags.  Surprisingly the remaining questions below have my favorite tags, but I have never bothered scrolling down cause I thought most wouldn't be my favorite tags anyway.

Comment: But my point is to have the homepage (or a new page) to contain EVERY question similar to when you select a specific tag.

Comment: It's "only" biased. So it doesn't block out anything that's not on your favorites unless it's one of your ignored tags. If there isn't anything in your tags, it'll fill up the spots with other ones - especially this time of the day when the site is less active.

Comment: I have 7 favorite tags currently, and most of them are pretty active.  So I'm suppose to add other tags to my ignored tags so I don't seem them in my homepage?

Comment: Asker, I agree with your statement.

Comment: @user152229 There are a LOT of tags that you'd need to put on your ignore list to see only your favorite ones. I remember seeing someone on meta complaining about having 1000+ tags on the ignored list... But yeah, that's where a feature request comes in.